# Login via ajax request only works on second try, fails on first

Tags: php, ajax, session, authentication

I am sending an ajax request to a php login backend that varyfies the user and password, starts a session and sends a positive or negative response.

The response is then translated to a user message by jquery and if the credentioals were correct, the user is redirected to the closed part of the site via

`window.location.href('mySecretSite.php')`

The problem is, that I am allways thrown back to the login site on first try of the browser session, because the next php script has no session and assumes the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of headache I worked it out.
The error was mine as usual. So I share it to give others the opportunity to learn from my stupidity.
The starting site of the backend was an index.html file which led to the browser not saving the session cookie PHPSESSID passed over by the ajax response.

Changing the startpage of the "secretsite" to index.php fixed the bug entirely.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: reqUrl,
    data: reqBody,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        if (data.redirect) {
            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
        else {
            // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
            $("#myform").replaceWith(data.form);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I did this. But it was not the problem. Solution was that You shoul not have an html entry page for a session based ajax-login system as the browser does not eat the phpsessid cookie sent to it by the ajax respond in an html page. Me silly.